# How does the compareTo() method work using the listIterator in my code?

Tags: java

I have a problem understanding the **while loop** from the ***addInOrder()*** method below because of the ***compareTo()*** method used with a listIterator. I'll post the code below and the part that I haven't understood.

```java
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> placesToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
        placesToVisit.add("Sydney");
        placesToVisit.add("Melbourne");
        placesToVisit.add("Brisbane");
        placesToVisit.add("Perth");
        placesToVisit.add("Canberra");
        placesToVisit.add("Adelaide");
        placesToVisit.add("Darwin");
        printList(placesToVisit);

     private static void printList(LinkedList<String> linkedList) {
        Iterator<String> i= linkedList.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Now visiting " + i.next());
        }
        System.out.println("=========================");
    }

     private static boolean addInOrder(LinkedList<String> linkedList, String newCity) {
        ListIterator<String> stringListIterator = linkedList.listIterator();

        while(stringListIterator.hasNext()) {
            int comparison = stringListIterator.next().compareTo(newCity);
            if(comparison == 0) { // equal, do not add
                System.out.println(newCity + " is already included as a destination");
                return false;
            } else if(comparison > 0) { // new City should appear before this one
                stringListIterator.previous();
                stringListIterator.add(newCity);
                return true;
            } else if(comparison < 0) {
                // move on next city
            }
         }

        stringListIterator.add(newCity); //adds a city in case the linkedList passed as a parameter is empty.
        return true;
    }
```

So, talking about the ***addInOrder*** method. I understand that by having stated **ListIterator stringListIterator = linkedList.listIterator();** , the cursor for the iterator will be located before the first element of the linked list, which, following the example, is *Sydney*.

Suppose the order of the cities added to the linked list is the one used in the ***main*** method: *Sydney*, *Melbourne*, *Brisbane*, *Perth*, *Canberra*, *Adelaide* and *Darwin*.

Now, regarding the **while loop**: The line **int comparison = stringListIterator.next().compareTo(newCity);** moves the cursor after the first element, which is *Sydney*, and it will compare *Sydney* to the newCity parameter. Let's say that the newCity parameter that I want to pass is *Adelaide*. It will compare *Sydney* to *Adelaide* and after the comparison it will result 18 because *Sydney* is "greater than" *Adelaide*, so it will enter the **else if(comparison>0)** condition;

by having stated: **stringListIterator.previous();** the cursor will get back to the initial place, and by this, I mean before the first element, *Sydney*. The second line, **stringListIterator.add(newCity);** will add, in my case, *Adelaide*, as the first element of the linkedList, *Sydney* being after it.

My problem is after that: Because it's a while loop, it will re-do the code, but here comes the problem for me: By reaching again **int comparison = stringListIterator.next().compareTo(newCity);** , where the cursor will be located? It will move from between *Sydney* and *Melbourne* to between *Melbourne* and *Brisbane*? If so, then comparing *Melbourne* to the newCity parameter(*Adelaide* introduced like I said above), will result 12 because *Melbourne* is "greater than" *Adelaide*, and this again will check the condition **else if(comparison>0)** , it will enter it and so, **stringListIterator.previous();** will move the cursor now between *Sydney* and *Melbourne*, adding again *Adelaide*(like for the first comparison)?? I know something's missing from my logic, because the code actually orders all the cities alphabetically(that's the purpose of the code), but where do I make a mistake??? Please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Formatting tip: use backticks around code to format them in a fixed width font. `int x;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct; up to the point where you write "By reaching **again** `int comparison = stringListIterator.next().compareTo(newCity);`" (emphasis added)

If you study the `else if` note that there is a `return true`. This means that you do not reach the while again.

```java
...
} else if(comparison > 0) { // new City should appear before this one   
   stringListIterator.previous();
   stringListIterator.add(newCity);
   return true;
} else { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! That helped me a lot. It's so silly of me to not realize that having the return there, the loop will actually end. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
int comparison = stringListIterator.next().compareTo(newCity);
```

Part of your confusion is because this line of code does too many things. To understand what it is doing, split it into two lines:

```
String city = stringListIterator.next();
int comparison = city.compareTo(newCity);
```

Now you can also add output to see what is happening:

```
String city = stringListIterator.next();
System.out.println("city: " + city);
int comparison = city.compareTo(newCity);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate your help! I actually figured it out now with your help and almac777's.